# Is/was General Leia Organa expected to be in the next episodes (VIII and IX) of Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, production, princess-leia, the-rise-of-skywalker

With the death of Carrie Fisher, does it have any impact on the next *Star Wars* films, episodes VIII and IX? Was she slated to be on 8-9? Has principal photography started with her on camera?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

### She *is* in Episode VIII, filming is complete, and her scenes will not be changed.

General Leia Organa was played by Carrie Fisher, who was [definitely going to be](http://www.detroitnews.com/story/entertainment/movies/2017/03/26/carrie-fisher-star-wars-last-jedi-scenes-will-changed/99605700/) in *The Last Jedi* (Episode VIII):

> **“She’s in ‘VIII,’ and we’re not changing eight to deal with her
> passing,**” Disney Chief Executive Bob Iger said during an on-stage
> conversation with his wife, Willow Bay, on Thursday at a conference
> hosted by USC’s Marshall and Annenberg schools. “Her performance,
> which we’ve been really pleased with, remains as it was.”

That is in accord with earlier information indicating that Fisher would be in *The Last Jedi*, e.g. [this article](http://www.slashfilm.com/star-wars-episode-viii-cast/), in which Fisher’s appearance was confirmed by Kathleen Kennedy, head of Lucasfilm:

> Speaking to Bang Showbiz (via the Evening Standard) at Star Wars: The
> Force Awakens London premiere, Lucasfilm president Kathleen Kennedy
> confirmed that pretty much everyone would be back for the next
> installment of the series. “**There will be a handful of new cast
> members in Episode VIII but also all the cast members you see here
> tonight will be in it as well**,” she said.
>
> Cast members in attendance included Harrison Ford, Mark Hamill, **Carrie
> Fisher**, Peter Mayhew, Daisy Ridley, John Boyega, Oscar Isaac,
> Gwendoline Christie, Lupita Nyong’o, Max von Sydow, and Adam Driver,
> so make of that what you will. It’s worth keeping in mind that this
> exchange took place a day or so before the film actually hit theaters,
> so it’s not as if Kennedy were about to start spilling spoilers right
> there on the red carpet.

In addition, she [was](https://moviepilot.com/p/carrie-fishers-episode-8-role-may-be-expanding-during-star-wars-reshoots/4104830) [said](https://www.instagram.com/p/BKYfbWuj3ch/) to have been absent from New York Comiccon due to “Star Wars production,” a sure sign that she had a role in the film:

[image]

As further evidence, Oscar Isaac, who plays Poe Dameron in Episodes VII, VIII, and possibly IX, [shared an set picture](https://www.facebook.com/OfficialOscarIsaacPage/photos/a.915066005201699.1073741826.204654052909568/1330287570346205/?type=3&theater) of Leia. It is possible, however, that it is from *The Force Awakens*.

Carrie Fisher completed her filming for Episode VIII, at least according to [this article.](http://variety.com/2016/film/news/carrie-fisher-dead-death-star-wars-viii-8-1201948826/) In addition, the shooting for VIII [is finished](http://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-episode-viii-wraps-shooting):

> Director Rian Johnson announced today on the official Star Wars
> Facebook and Twitter channels that Star Wars: Episode VIII has wrapped
> shooting. “Final slate of the final shot,” Johnson wrote of an
> accompanying short video. “**VIII is officially wrapped**. Thanks to the
> best cast and crew in the galaxy, and thanks to the fans for all the
> love and support through the whole process. Cannot wait to put it
> together and share it with you all!”

This would also tend to suggest that all Fisher’s scenes are filmed.

In addition, there will not be scenes added to *The Last Jedi* through the CGI technology used to resurrect Wilhuff Tarkin in *Rogue One*:

> Iger and Bay also noted Fisher’s scenes in “The Last Jedi” wouldn’t be
> modified using hologram technology. Disney had used a digital
> re-creation of a late actor in a previous “Star Wars” film.
>
> “We’re not doing that with Carrie,” Iger said, describing the upcoming
> film as “just as satisfying” as the last “Stars Wars.”

### She is in IX

[We know](http://www.etonline.com/news/179765_colin_trevorrow_promises_satisfying_answer_to_star_wars_theories/) that Fisher had a planned role in Episode IX, since the Episode IX director discussed what he wanted to do with Luke and Leia’s characters:

> Though he says he has yet to speak with original Star Wars stars
> Hamill and Carrie Fisher, Trevorrow wants their presence to be even
> greater in his film, revealing he can’t wait “to find new places that
> we can take those characters.”
>
> “They are icons, but they’re also people that have suffered tremendous
> loss and challenge over the course of all these films,” he told us.

Initially, the filmrunners claimed that she would not be in the film. [Kennedy claimed](http://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/lucasfilm-president-kathleen-kennedy-carrie-fisher-episode-ix/story?id=46807515) that at the time of Fisher's death, Episode IX did not even have a finished script. As such, contrary to comments made by certain other individuals (namely Todd Fisher), Carrie Fisher will **not be in Episode IX**.

> INTERVIEWER: Todd Fisher has said that his sister, that Carrie will be a part of Episode IX. In what capacity—were you using preshot footage, or...?
>
> KENNEDY: You know that was probably—he was probably—confused. Because we finished
> everything in VIII, and and Carrie is absolutely phenomenal in the
> movie, and we're so happy that we were able to complete shooting in
> the summer. Unfortunately, Carrie passed away. So, by the time we
> were...well underway with Episode IX, in our thoughts. We had not
> written the script yet. But we've regrouped, we started over again in
> January, so.... Sadly, Carrie will not be in IX.

This was in accordance with other official statements. [According to the Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2017/jan/13/carrie-fisher-disney-negotiating-for-digital-rights-star-wars), Disney has said that they have not been trying to get the rights to Carrie Fisher’s image:

> But in a statement the Walt Disney Company said: “Disney is not in
> conversations with the estate of Carrie Fisher at this time and any
> reports to the contrary are false.”

They also [asserted](http://www.starwars.com/news/a-statement-regarding-new-rumors) that they will not use CGI to put Leia in future films:

> We don’t normally respond to fan or press speculation, but there is a
> rumor circulating that we would like to address. We want to assure our
> fans that Lucasfilm has no plans to digitally recreate Carrie Fisher’s
> performance as Princess or General Leia Organa.

However, this was all quite false: Leia does appear in the film, and her role, while not as extensive as in previous films, is not minor, either.

Comment: It being in pre-production doesn't really imply anything of the sort. It does mean that, should Leia survive VIII, a solution must be made for IX.

Comment: @Terriblefan - Doesn’t imply what? That her scenes are not filmed? Doesn’t it at least make it likely?

Comment: @Terriblefan, _would not have done any filming_ supposedly means that Carrie Fisher had not done any filming before her death, not that she would not have done any filming at all (which seems to be the way you understood it).

Comment: "even using a CGI version of Fisher, as was recently done with the character of Tarkin in Rogue One." – SPOILERS: Also with the character of Princess Leia herself.

Comment: @tobiasvl I agree to an extent, but this question is about future works, so there's kind of a penchant for spoiler-y material to begin with...

Comment: @tobiasvl How is it a spoiler that Tarkin is in Rogue One?

Comment: @spacetyper I meant it's a spoiler that Leia is in Rogue One. It's kind of a surprise scene.

Comment: You forgot the third alternative: they keep Leia's role in IX but shoot with a new actress...

Comment: I was wondering how they got a Tarkin to look so similar.

Comment: @Bakuriu: *that* would probably draw the wrath of the fans. Wilhuff Tarkin showing up long after the actor who played him (RIP Peter Cushing 1913-1994) died is one thing - CGI-ing one of the iconic characters is quite another. I expect that her character will die off-screen. "General Organa died in an XXXXX on YYYYY" seems like a likely way to explain away her permanent absence.

Comment: @BobJarvis I'm a fan and I don't find changing the actor enraging at all.

Comment: @BobJarvis I would rather she be in an opening scene CGI-ed and then immediately killed 3-4 minutes into the film than her die off camera. That's cheezy. She's a main character. It'd be one thing for her to die in the 30 year gap. It's another to kill her between two movies and not even show it. It's an important event. They can at least show it to us.

Comment: you may want to update that SW team has said he will NOT use CGI to put her in the films --- http://www.starwars.com/news/a-statement-regarding-new-rumors

Comment: @Skooba - I added that, as well as another piece of information I found about Disney’s lack of plans for a CGI Leia.

Comment: I SINCERLY hope if they go down another person portraying her route...that they make a better job there than the guys who did mummy 3........the actress was so different that it just disturbed me the whole film and in the german translation at least the voice of her was so different that it just didn't seem to fit to the character at all.....

Comment: Given today's update about Disney responding to rumors about CGI Leia, I wonder if this discussion/thread was a part of rumor mill they are responding to. That's cool to think we might have influenced their decision to speak up on the topic

Comment: Episode 8 - [The Last Jedi](https://twitter.com/StarWarsUK/status/823561402698895367/photo/1?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)...

Comment: There is another possibility: they might tweak the script for VIII and/or take a couple of scenes originally filmed for VIII and work them into the script for IX, to give her a minimal on-screen presence, with the rest of her role on the story "implied" or "referred to". It's not necessarily likely, but it could happen.

Comment: Mark my prediction.   They will make last minute changes to TLJ, possibly involving reshoots and doubles so that Leia dies in this film.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Probably not. See the new information.

Comment: Confirmed in Star Wars 9, but only as flashback; http://www.nydailynews.com/entertainment/late-carrie-fisher-final-star-wars-movie-article-1.3030154

Comment: Would you please update this answer now that the cast list for 9 has been officially announced?

Comment: Indeed. Not immediately, though.

Comment: half of this answer is now incorrect

Answer (score 17):

## Carrie Fisher Will Be In Episode IX

As of July 2018, Lucasfilm has announced that the late Carrie Fisher will be appearing in *Star Wars: Episode IX* [in their cast list](https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-episode-ix-cast-announced) using unused footage from *Episode VII: The Force Awakens*:

> Joining the cast of Episode IX are Naomi Ackie, Richard E. Grant, and Keri Russell, who will be joined by veteran Star Wars actors Mark Hamill, Anthony Daniels, and Billy Dee Williams, who will reprise his role as Lando Calrissian.
>
> **The role of Leia Organa will once again be played by Carrie Fisher, using previously unreleased footage shot for Star Wars: The Force Awakens.** “We desperately loved Carrie Fisher,” says Abrams. “Finding a truly satisfying conclusion to the Skywalker saga without her eluded us. **We were never going to recast, or use a CG character. With the support and blessing from her daughter, Billie, we have found a way to honor Carrie’s legacy and role as Leia in Episode IX by using unseen footage we shot together in Episode VII."**

Answer (score 10):

Principal photography on Episode VIII is already complete - it was announced on [July 22nd, 2016](http://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-episode-viii-wraps-shooting). What role General Organa plays in the film is currently unknown.

We also do not know how the films will handle moving forward after the loss of Ms. Fisher. It's really far too early for any official statement or official reaction to the event.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that she was supposed to appear. [Here](http://heavy.com/news/2016/12/carrie-fisher-death-dead-affect-star-wars-episode-8-9-filming-production-delay-leia-organa-role/) are some more details:

> Filming for this movie ended long before Fisher’s death, with
>   production concluding in July 2016. An official from Lucasfilm
>   confirmed to TMZ on Tuesday that Fisher had no scenes left to film for
>   Episode VIII.

Answer (score 2):

As of July 27, 2018, Carrie Fisher will be in both Episode 8 and 9.

> The role of Leia Organa will once again be played by Carrie Fisher, using previously unreleased footage shot for Star Wars: The Force Awakens. “We desperately loved Carrie Fisher,” says Abrams. “Finding a truly satisfying conclusion to the Skywalker saga without her eluded us. We were never going to recast, or use a CG character. With the support and blessing from her daughter, Billie, we have found a way to honor Carrie’s legacy and role as Leia in Episode IX by using unseen footage we shot together in Episode VII.”
>
> <sub>*https://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-episode-ix-cast-announced*</sub>

Previously, the president of Lucasfilm had stated Carrie Fisher would not appear in Episode 9, but apparently they changed their mind.

> Carrie Fisher won’t appear in “Star Wars: Episode IX,” after all.
>
> Lucasfilm president Kathleen Kennedy made the reveal during an interview with ABC News on Friday at the “Star Wars Celebration” in Orlando.
>
> “Sadly, Carrie will not be in ‘Nine,'” Kennedy said. “But we’ll see a lot of her in ‘Eight,’ which is great.”
>
> <sub>*https://variety.com/2017/film/news/carrie-fisher-not-in-star-wars-episode-ix-1202031153/*</sub>

On April 14, 2017, Good Morning America tweeted a clip where this topic is discussed with Kathy Kennedy, president of Lucasfilms. The clip can be viewed [here](https://twitter.com/GMA/status/853001259820994562).

Comment: They had to come out with this after [her son's comments](https://arstechnica.com/the-multiverse/2017/04/star-wars-episode-9-carrie-fisher-no-cgi/)

Comment: Would you please update this answer now that the cast list for 9 has been officially announced?